# Lookup AWS IAM role using tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, lookup, amazon-eks

Could you help me with the problem of getting AWS IAM role name via terraform?

Briefly, I have a previously created role with the name: **test-platform-testenv-eks2020041915272704860006**.
Different roles have different names with variables (platform/stack names) in their names.
Now I have a Terraform file that must get the name of this IAM role (to attach a policy to this role).
I can do it using the exact name of the role.
But how to do it without hard code (knowing tags and some other parameters of this role)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make it an input parameter to the template?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

We can't use the output from the previous (eks) stack creation.
I was trying Data Source: aws_iam_role and find using tags, but the required parameter of Data Source: aws_iam_role is name and we can't use masks in it.

Comment: Write a script to find the role given whatever custom criteria you want (e.g. tags) and then provide that as an input to the next set of infrastructure.

Comment: I think it's a good idea. But the customer's standard allows only terraform code in this stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution. Maybe not the best, but it works for me. So,

1. Get iam_instance_profile of the created EKS node using **data "aws_instance"**, for example:

```
data "aws_instance" "eks_node" {
  filter {...}
}
```

2. Get role name of the previously created EKS node using **data "aws_iam_instance_profile"** (from defined in step 1 aws_instance), for example:

```
data "aws_iam_instance_profile" "eks_node_profile" {
  name = data.aws_instance.eks_node.iam_instance_profile
}
```

3. Attach the newly created policy to the previously defined EKS role, for example:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_policy_to_eks" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.created_policy_eks.arn
  role       = data.aws_iam_instance_profile.eks_node_profile.role_name
}
```

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the role name in an [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ssm_parameter.html) as part of the original stack.

The subsequent stack can then pick the role name from the Parameter Store using the [`aws_ssm_parameter` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ssm_parameter.html) like in the following snippet:

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "role" {
  name = "/path/to/role/name"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "policy-attachment" {
  roles = ["${data.aws_ssm_parameter.role.value}"] # pull value from parameter store
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll ask the customer about AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store resource. But in case of its absence, I will have to continue finding a solution.